# Vectorization - how to append array without loop for

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code:

```
x = range(100)
M = len(x)
sample=np.zeros((M,41632))
for i in range(M):
    lista=np.load('sample'+str(i)+'.npy')
    for j in range(41632):
        sample[i,j]=np.array(lista[j])
     print i
```

to create an array made of sample_i numpy arrays.

sample0, sample1, sample3, etc. are numpy arrays and my expected output is a Mx41632 array like this:

```
sample = [[sample0],[sample1],[sample2],...]
```

How can I compact and make more quick this operation without loop for? M can reach also 1 million.

Or, how can I append my sample array if the starting point is, for example, 1000 instead of 0?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a minimal and verifiable example to your question. It's not clear what kind of arrays you're dealing with and what's the expected output.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Is now clear?

Comment: @user23299 if one of the answers has helped you, consider accepting or commenting on why it hasn't answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Initial load

You can make your code a lot faster by avoiding the inner loop and not initialising `sample` to zeros.

```
x = range(100)
M = len(x)
sample = np.empty((M, 41632))
for i in range(M):
    sample[i, :] = np.load('sample'+str(i)+'.npy')
```

In my tests this took the reading code from 3 seconds to 60 miliseconds!

## Adding rows

In general it is very slow to change the size of a numpy array. You can append a row once you have loaded the data in this way:

```
sample = np.insert(sample, len(sample), newrow, axis=0)
```

but this is almost never what you want to do, because it is so slow.

## Better storage: HDF5

Also if M is very large you will probably start running out of memory.

I recommend that you have a look at [PyTables](https://www.pytables.org) which will allow you to store your sample results in one HDF5 file and manipulate the data without loading it into memory. This will in general be a lot faster than the .npy files you are using now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Once I stored for example the first 5000 data,Is there a way to restart the code from 5001 appending the new values to the stored array?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by restarting the code. Do you mean to add extra columns to `sample` once the code above has already run and `sample` is still in memory?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: I've added a note about adding rows. In general, this is not what you want to do. If you're storing this much data (millions of rows) I really recommend you to try pytables.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple with numpy. Consider this example:

```
import numpy as np
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
#create an array with 4 rows and 3 columns
arr = np.zeros([4,3])
arr[:,:] = l
```

You can also insert rows or columns separately:

```
#insert the first row
arr[0,:] = l[0]
```

You just have to provide that dimensions are the same.

Comment: Thanks. How can I load quickly thousands of .npy arrays without loop for? The problem is that the loop for takes hours to load thousands of arrays

Comment: I don't think you can get around this. You can append to the array using the optimized numpy method, but I don't think you can do anything with loading files. Probably accessing memory on the hard drive (loading files) takes the most time, but you can't get around it.

Comment: However, you might want to use some serialization (e.g. pickle) to save the big array when it's ready. Then you can use it whenever you want. Deserialization of such a big array should be much faster than loading thousands of files.